# AnyChart Axis Rotation and Label Positioning

Tags: charts, rotation, label, axes, anychart

In this example https://playground.anychart.com/Cjb94yIM I have a chart with very long axis label texts.
This is all good, until the labels are rotated. Since the labels are centered, it now looks like they belong to the record next to it. I have commented out code in the example on how I want the labels to be and how I think they should be. Unfortunately, the chart does not scale properly when you adjust the position of the labels. Is that a bug? I don't know how to scale the chart correctly so that you can see everything. And so that the resize still works correctly.

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current version of the library 8.8.0 doesn't provide a solution to meet your requirements. The rotated labels have an anchor in the label center, so a long label can cover the neighbor category. The current API doesn't provide a possibility to anchor the start of the label right in the category.

Comment: Are there any news on this topic in version 8.9.0?

Comment: Unfortunately not, this feature was not scheduled in the 8.9.0 roadmap.